# What is the purpose of `require_recipient`?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions, action

I saw the description of the function `require_recipient` and it says:

> Add the specified account to set of accounts to be notified

I would like to understand what's the purpose of receive this notification of a transaction. What are the practical real scenarios examples for dApps that we use it?

I saw that being used on `transfer` action of `eosio.token`, I see this notification in my nodeos log but I want to understand it with more details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think of it as sending a carbon copy of the action. Since `eosio.token` does it with `transfer`, contracts can monitor and respond to deposits. e.g. if user `a` transfers EOS to contract `b`, then `b` could automatically transfer another token type back to `a`, creating a simple exchange.

Comment: Thanks Todd! Do you mind to give me a smart contract code example in how to "watch" another contract transaction? Like, how can I watch for my contract an `eosio.token transfer` action?

Comment: Here's an example. Firefox (fastest) or Chrome (slow load): https://tbfleming.github.io/cib/eos.html#gist=d230f3ab2998e8858d3e51af7e4d9aeb

Comment: That's perfect my friend, things are clear now, so if I understood correctly the name of the action in my recipient contract must have the **same name** of the "emitter" contract and always have two parameters: `uint64_t self` and `uint64_t code`, then I execute unpack_action_data with the struct of the "emitter" contract ABI.