# Is there event emitting function in smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, event

I am porting Ethereum smart contract in Solidity to EOS platform, but I meet a problem: how to send some events to Dapp so as to update the UI? 
Now I have to poll the table the smart contract saved to get the status.

Is there event emitting function in EOS smart contract? Or is there another better solution to get the smart contract internal data?

Comment: Currently, it is not really supported https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4003

Comment: This is a bit ridiculous, no events. Seriously, I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [demux](https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js) library for listening to EOS blockchain events. As far as I know there is no event logs like in Ethereum so you have to poll the api node

- https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js

Answer (score 2):

Currently, an event system like on the ethereum blockchain is not really supported. There are two github issues of the eos code that mention this feature, but say that it is not directly supported

In https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4003#issuecomment-400155409 the poster says that you currently could achieve this by using a plugin on your own nodeos server.

In https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/1640#issuecomment-375488939 Dan says that it is possible, but the tooling is still being developed.

Comment: This one has been flagged as a low-quality answer, please include the answering content in your answer and use the link as reference.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `require_recipient(dapp_acc)` and from your node you will listen and receive it, then you can broadcast to your dapp.

Comment: To listen and receive it, must this be implemented within the node as a "plugin"? Then the plugin can do whatever it wants (arbitrary C++ code)?

Comment: `require_recipient` is more about relaying actions than notifying clients

Comment: See https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/128/what-is-the-purpose-of-require-recipient