# How should I get the data of the multi_index database?(about contract)

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

The return value of the action function can only be void type.
I can't get data by return value. Now I have saved multiple objects in the multi_index database. I want to get them at once, what should I do?
help me please.

Comment: Please keep this discussion in English and provide some additional infos. Quick shot: have a look at the RPC calls: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows

Comment: Are you looking for an event system like in ethereum? Then possible duplicate: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/347/is-there-event-emitting-function-in-smart-contract

Comment: yes.I want to get the data in the contract from the web page. I have solved it and can be solved by "get_table_rows".thanks...
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it and can be solved by "get_table_rows".
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows